# Django mptt, extends "base.html"

Tags: django, django-mptt

In base.html:

```
<div id="menu_shop">
            <input name="search" placeholder="search">
            <p>Category:</p>
             {% load mptt_tags %}
<ul class="root">
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li>
            {{ node.name }}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
</div>
```

in views:

```
def show_category_tree(request):
    return render_to_response("base.html",
                              {'nodes': Category.tree.all()},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^category/', 'item.views.show_category_tree'),
url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[\w\-_]+)/$', 'item.views.by_category'),
```

How to display this in "by_category.html"

If I try(for example):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}
{% for e in entries %}
<p><b>{{ e.name}}</b></p>

<p>{{ e.desc}}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I have this error:

http://dpaste.com/810809/

{% extends "base.html" %} does not work. If I remove it, everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this error because your template context for the `by_category` does not include `nodes`.

The `extends` tag is related to the template, not the view. It makes your `by_category.html` template extend the `base.html` template, but it does not include the template context from any other view.

The easiest fix would be to add `nodes` to your template context in the `by_category` view.

```
def by_category(request, slug):
    entries = Entry.objects.filter(...)
    return render_to_response("base.html",
        {'entries': entries,
         'nodes': Category.tree.all()},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This would be repetitive if you want to display the nodes in lots of other views. If you want to include the nodes in all views, you may want to write a request context processor. If you want to include it in some but not all pages, then try writing a custom template tag.